# Round Robin Database in Python 3.6+

Tags: python, rrdtool, rrd

I want to build a Round Robin Database in Python for some time series data. I've looked at several Python modules (PyRRD, py-rrdtool, python-rrdtool, rrdtool), but as far as I can see, none of them offer support for Python 3.6+. Any suggestions as to how I can implement a rrd database in Python 3.6+?

I tried installing python-rrdtool with pip install python-rrdtool but the result I get is:

```
Collecting python-rrdtool
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/af/bf46df3104d78591f942278467a1016d056a887c808ed1127207a4e1ebaf/python-rrdtool-1.4.7.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/python-rrdtool/setup.py", line 61
    os.chmod(executable, 0777)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

----------------------------------------

    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/python-rrdtool/
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: So what happened when you tried to update pip?

Comment: I hadn't before you asked, updated it now, same result when installing python-rrdtool

Comment: Use ```python -m pip``` or a virtualenv instead of system pip. Apparently this is a big issue at least on ubuntu when using the system pip instead of the userspace one or whatever see here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/726850/pip-upgrade-not-working

Comment: No that's still not working. I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Which is not working the update or the install of python-rrdtool?

Comment: install python-rrdtool. I've upgraded pip without an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192035/discussion-between-west-and-c-acarbay).

Comment: Solved it with the help of @West. Turns out I need to read the docs better and install dependencies. Also python -m pip install works and pip install alone doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps installing the RRDTool package first may fix the issue, on Ubuntusomething like:

```
sudo apt-get install librrd-dev libpython-dev
```

Worked for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> [python-rrdtool](https://github.com/commx/python-rrdtool) Python bindings for RRDtool with a native C extension.
>
> Supported Python versions: 2.6+, 3.3+.
>
> The bindings are based on the code of the original Python 2 bindings
>   for rrdtool by Hye-Shik Chang, which are currently shipped as official
>   bindings with rrdtool.
>
> Note: python-rrdtool is now the official rrdtool Python binding and
>   shipped with the upstream distribution.

Comment: I tried installing python-rrdtool, it didn't work. I appended the error message to the question.